# In Visual Studio, how do you reconfigure Service Reference based on Solution Configuration

Tags: visual-studio

When I create a service reference in our lab environment, I use the lab instance of a service and my solution Config="Debug".

When I'm ready to deploy my application, I have to reconfigure the service reference to use the production instance of the service and set Config="Release."

I've tried creating multiple Service References in solutions with different names, but that requires either using Object type and Directcast or a lot of "#If Config=..." statements.

What I want is to configure a Service Reference for one URL when Config="Debug" and a different URL for Config="Release."

***So, my question is how do *you* handle multiple instances of Service References for the different environments you work in?***